# WAS 8.5.5. web app getting NoSuchFieldError during startup

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, websphere

I have a maven web app, using WAS 8.5.5.

On app startup I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE

This means there's some sort of mismatch of jars (httpclient & httpcore) in my classpath.

To get more info, I ran the following code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Test.class.getClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class");
log.info("Outputting resoure info: " + resource.getFile() + " " + resource.getPath() + " " + resource.getRef());
          try {
                 log.info(FileLocator.resolve(resource));
                 log.info(FileLocator.toFileURL(resource));
          } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

This gave me the following output:

> start Outputting resoure info:
>   /org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class
>   /org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class null  start
>   jar:file:/C:/RAD9.0/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_2/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar!/org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class
>   start
>   file:/C:/RAD9.0/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_2/profiles/AppSrv01/servers/server1/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/105/1/.cp/org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class

These are both obviously loaded to WAS on startup. How do I stop this from happening? I tried changing the priority of the module loading in the app settings by setting load parent last, but that stopped the app from coming up at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can also see where the offending class is loaded from using the Class Loader Viewer and searching for it.  You have to enable this first by clicking Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Class loader viewer service, enable the service and restart the server.

[image]

As a quick fix, without having to switch to PARENT_LAST and create a shared library, I copied the JAR file from my .m2/repo folder to the AppServ/lib directory.

```
> cp C:\path\to\your\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.3\httpcore-4.3.3.jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib"
```

Then I added an entry to the JVM classpath within the server console:

Open https://localhost:9043/ibm/console and go to:

Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name. Then, in the Server Infrastructure section, click Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual machine

Then enter the following under "Classpath"

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/httpcore-4.3.3.jar
```

Use a semicolon to separate entries.

Restart to retest.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a library in your application at a newer version than a copy in the application server so you end up with a mix of classes visible to your application. As you notice this is a bad thing.

There are a few ways to get around this, but the simplest is to change the classloader order to load classes from your application before the runtime. You can do this in the admin console by navigating to the application, selecting classloading and choosing the radio button labeled *Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)*.

If you do this though you should make sure you don't include the Java EE packages in your application though (that sometimes happens with maven built applications).

Comment: Hi Alasdair. Thanks for taking the time to reply! I have tried to set the settings on the WAS server to PARENT_LAST, and that introduces other complexities.

com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype

Comment: OK, I got a bit further. I've set it to PARENT_LAST, I've created a new shared library which points to my jars, and what's happening now is that I'm getting some spring initialization issues... which is interesting.

I'm not entirely happy with this solution because I don't have to have to upload jars to the server and maintain them. I'd rather that was done at the application level.